# Microsoft Teams Change Notification Subscription validation error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We have implemented Change notification for Microsoft Teams channel messages and the subscription and renewal worked well. Suddenly we received the following error :

```
error: {
    'InvalidRequest',
    message: 'Subscription validation request failed. Response must exactly match validationToken query parameter.',
        innerError: {
            date: '2020-10-07T06:27:51',
            'request-id': '1f5b7190-d2ab-459a-a9de-a086cc1a8584',
            'client-request-id': '1f5b7190-d2ab-459a-a9de-a086cc1a8584'
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally we are receiving lot of life cycle notification from Microsoft Teams with and its payload is empty.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There must be an issue with validation token. Please use below code:  `if (Request.QueryString["validationToken"] != null)

 {​​

 var token = Request.QueryString["validationToken"];

 return Content(token, "text/plain");

 }​​
`

Comment: We still have the same issue.
We are using Hapi JS(v16.x). It automatically decodes the query string using https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_urlobject_query .
 We tried the validationToken with the decoded string as well as without decoded that by getting the validationToken from the url itself.

Comment: The document says decode and send the response back. The solution above is not decoding the token. And with the combinations also it is not worked . Please provide additional information

Comment: We tried Subscription on Express JS and got the same error. Its like we got the access for Protected APIs but could not able to use them . We are ready to provide any additional information to resolve this issue. Please let us know what other information is needed to fix this issue.

Comment: Its almost 21 days and we tried all the possibilities to resolve the issue. Could you please  provide the details for getting Premium support to resolve this quickly as it really needed for to satisfy the Customer ?